# Are there any differences between these two drop implementations for a singly-linked list

Tags: rust

I'm working through *[Learning Rust with Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/first-drop.html)* and had a question about the drop implementation for the initial linked list from that book. The linked list is composed of a stack allocated link, which is either empty or points to a heap allocated Node with some associated data.

```rust
struct List {
    head: Link,
}

enum Link {
    Empty,
    More(Box<Node>),
}

struct Node {
    data: i32,
    next: Link,
}
```

The implementation of the drop trait given in the book uses `std::mem::replace` to take ownership of the nodes in the list.

```rust
// Copied from the book, omitting comments
impl Drop for List {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let mut cur_link = mem::replace(&mut self.head, Link::Empty);
        while let Link::More(mut boxed_node) = cur_link {
            cur_link = mem::replace(&mut boxed_node.next, Link::Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm confused why the book is using `mem::replace` to take ownership of the next pointer of the node. It seems like we already have owndership of `boxed_node` from the `while let` line and we can just set cur_link to `node.next` instead of using `mem::replace`.

I wrote this alternative implementation which compiles just fine. I'm wondering if there is any difference between the two drop methods.

```rust
impl Drop for List {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let mut link = mem::replace(&mut self.head, Link::Empty);
        while let Link::More(node) = link {
            link = node.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are right. My guess is that an early version did `impl Drop for Node`, that will work with the original code but not with your changes ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2eb8ba829e56b579676fe1287de6b8e1)). However in the `github` [history](https://github.com/rust-unofficial/too-many-lists/commits/master/src/first-drop.md) it seems to have been this way forever.

Comment: It's also worth noting the same issue @rodrigo mentioned applies when making the types generic - so I wouldn't be surprised if the book's version of the code was originally based on a generic version, and just specialized for `i32`.

Comment: Also worth noting that _neither_ version works if `Link` has a `Drop` impl.

Comment: @apetranzilla Even if it was generic, it works fine in both versions. (see [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=315850c4798ca117c0f16cc48f771394))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely right. The whole point of implementing `Drop` in that tutorial is to avoid a recursive call, and your implementation achieves the same thing using less code (and with less assembly at the end).

Having said that, the implementation in the tutorial is a lot more explicit, and it could be argued that it is easier to see what is going on. The `mem::replace` ensures that the `Link` is replaced with an `Empty`, making it clear that all of the boxes are dropped too. This might have been a conscious decision by the tutorial authors, or it could have been an oversight.

The [bonus section](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/first-drop.html#bonus-section-for-premature-optimization) might also give a clue as to what the author was thinking. Their idea of simplifying the `Drop` implementation was to add a method which is useful for simplifying other methods too, and therefore would still need to maintain the integrity of the structure. The fact that this isn't necessary in a `Drop` implementation may have passed them by while looking at the bigger picture, or else they may have specifically wanted that implementation so that the bonus section makes sense.

Your version is probably more efficient, but might take a second glance to understand what it is really doing. I'd still go with yours though, since it is shorter and is doing less work.